# Pull request from same repository

Tags: github

I want to protect my master branch so my team cannot directly merge their code to it without approval.

Is it possible to do a pull request from a branch inside the parent repository?

I know if someone forks the repo they can then do a pull request but my workflow is that we commit to a branch on the main repository first that is assigned to a deployment slot for testing.  I am not worried about protecting these branches as they just deploy to testing slots.

My master branch deploys to production so I want some way for team member to request their branch be merged to master.

Is there anyway to generate a pull request between branches?  What workflow would you suggest?

Comment: Have you _tried_ creating a pull request between arbitrary branches of the same repository? That would probably have been just as fast as posting this question, and you would have gotten an answer sooner. Trying things and seeing if they work is a big part of software development. So is reading [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-pull-request).

Comment: If you've never done a pull request before I think this is a fairly valid question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can protect the master branch in the branch settings so that no one can push commits to the master branch.

you end up having multiple branches in your main repo based on their purpose:

1. master branch(branch you use to build in production)
2. staging branch(Branch you use to make tests in the staging environment)
3. feature branch(Where you actually code)

> Name of the above branches is not strict, can be named according to relevance

So once you are done implementing your feature/fix/development you make a pull request to staging branch where the testers will test your branch. Once the testing is done and you want to move to production you make a pull request to master and merge.

Comment: Does pull request have to come from a fork?

Comment: It need not be a fork. You can create a branch on the same repo for yourself and make a pull request if you go to "settings">"branches">"branch protection rules" you can see that you can protect branches based on the pattern like "master" and add protection rules. "Require pull request reviews before merging" will make your master branch protected so that no one can commit to master directly  but can push to their branch and make a pull request to master